# F5 Big-IP, X-Forwarded-For and IIS Logs

Tags: iis-7, logging, isapi, f5-big-ip, x-forwarded-for

I've got an F5 Big-IP that is mangaged by our hosting provider. It's dedicated to our private VLAN, etc. Works great :)

We requested them to add in an X-Forwarded-For HTTP-Header field. They've done that and we can now access that in the code. Awesome :)

But .. for our IIS logs, it's still the IP of the F5 machine. I think I was told that we need to apply an ISAPI filter (cringe!) to the IIS server(s).

1. Can someone confirm this?
2. If #1 == yes, is there a file/instructions how to do this for our IIS7 web servers on windows 2008 machines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I published an ISAPI filter to work with our BIG-IP's and have just updated it with full x86 and x64 support.  Check out the blog post I wrote on it a while ago.  Just copy the enclosed F5XForwardedFor.dll to your server and reference it in the ISAPI section of your virtual site.

http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/joe/archive/2005/09/23/1492.aspx

Answer (score 6):

This is discussed in [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1154878.aspx) of the IIS Microsoft Community. It seems there is a [helper](http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/03/03/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr.aspx) to do that for IIS (Especifically stated to work with Microsoft ARR but it should work for any reverse proxy or load balancer).

Comment: Cheers! that looks like the answer i need :) I wonder why it wasn't added to IIS7 itself? weird.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is tagged with iis-7, this is the top hit when searching on X-Forwarded-For so I thought I would go ahead and provide this information for IIS 8.5.

**IIS 8.5 and later**
IIS 8.5 introduced the [Enhanced Logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85) feature that easily allows the administrator to log HTTP request headers such as X-Forwarded-For. This answer is adapted from the linked page.

1. Open **IIS Manager**.
2. Select the site or server in the **Connections** pane, and then double-click **Logging**. Note that enhanced logging is available only for site-level logging - if you select the server in the **Connections** pane, then the **Custom Fields** section of the **W3C Logging Fields** dialog is disabled.
3. In the **Format** field under **Log File**, select **W3C** and then click **Select Fields...**.
4. In the **W3C Logging Fields** dialog, click **Add Field...**. Note that enhanced logging is available only for site-level logging - if you selected the server in the **Connections** pane, then **Add Field...** is disabled.
5. In the **Add Custom Field** dialog, enter a **Field Name** such as `c-ip-original` to identify the custom field within the log file. Please note that the field name cannot contain spaces.
6. Select **Request Header** in the **Source Type** list.
7. Enter `X-FORWARDED-FOR` in **Source**.
8. Click **OK**.
9. Click **OK**.
10. Click **Apply** in the **Actions** pane to apply the new configuration.

Once the custom fields have been configured, IIS will create new text log files with "_x" appended to the file name to indicate that the file contains custom fields.

Note that the total size of data collected from all custom fields cannot exceed 65,536 bytes. If the total exceeds 65,536 bytes, then IIS will truncate the data.